# How to work with mPDF and diacritics?

Tags: php, diacritics, mpdf

Update: figured it out, see the comment below

I am trying to create a PDF file with mPDF from a HTML file. Everything works quite fine but one thing: in this HTML I must have some Romanian letters (șțâăîȘȚÂĂÎ, etc.) which are converted into symbols in the exported PDF file.

[image: How I get the pdf file, example]

My code:

```
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
//$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0); //the 'c' is not for multilanguage
$mpdf=new mPDF('','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0);//this one works

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list

$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('sursa.html'));

//$mpdf->Output();//we don't want to save file by hand
$mpdf->Output('output/output.pdf','F');
```

The source file example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

[...]

```
<p style="font-size: 3.2mm">
<b>I. Părțile discuției sunt:</b><br/>
<b>aaslasjf sșf asf ăîșțâ ȘȚÂĂÎ</b>
```

[...]

```
</body>
</html>
```

Did anyone work with special characters (latin) and knows how to fix this? Thanks a lot!
(update: it works now, see comments)

Comment: Figured it out, the wrong parameter 'c' from the object creation (`$mpdf=new mPDF('c'...`) was the culprit. If it remains empty string (blank), it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are encoding your page in UTF-8, or if you are using another character encoding that you specify it properly. See the mPDF documentation on [Input encoding](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=293).

Comment: It is:
1. See the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` line on top of the html file to be converted (I open it with file_get_contents('source.html')).

2. The file contains UTF-8 enconding and I run Ubuntu Linux (so no ANSI/whatever) file encoding is involved.

Comment: Figured it out, see the other comment above. It was because of 'c' parameter in the object creation code.

Comment: Just for reference: The `<meta>` tag doesn't encode your document in UTF-8 or any other character encoding, it just tells the user agent that your document is encoded in UTF-8, whether or not that's actually the case depends on the file/output itself.

Comment: True, it does not. But I checked that, of course ;) Geany (the editor I use) is on UTF-8 and the file system is also UTF-8, no problem there. PS: I had to mention the meta declaration because mPDF says it can detect it, so it could have been involved in my problem.

The problem was in `mPDF()` parameters, actually only the first one.